# Change input values bases on other input onChange

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks

Let's say I want to create a Converter, which means the input value should be changed based on another one.

just to see what I want to do in action https://calolocosta.github.io/romanNumeralsConverter/.

here's what I tried so far but couldn't make it

```js
function LightBulb() {
  let [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
  let [input2, setInput2] = useState("");

  const handleInput1 = (e) => {
    setInput2(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleInput2 = (e) => {
    setInput1(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input2}
        onChange={(e) => handleInput1(e)}
        placeholder="example 1000"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input1}
        onChange={(e) => handleInput2(e)}
        placeholder="example MCMXC"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

so what I want is to change the input2 value when input1 is typing and vice versa.
Here's the codesandbox that I have been working on: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-8o257, any idea would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will do the rests of the logic for that conversion. But as far as the inputs go and their interaction that needs to change the other one, here is the code changed:

```js
function LightBulb() {
  let [input1, setInput1] = useState("");
  let [input2, setInput2] = useState("");

  const handleInput1 = (e) => {
    setInput1(e.target.value);
    setInput2("Converted value");
  };

  const handleInput2 = (e) => {
    setInput2(e.target.value);
    setInput1("Converted value");
  };

  console.log(input2);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input1}
        onChange={(e) => handleInput1(e)}
        placeholder="example 1000"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={input2}
        onChange={(e) => handleInput2(e)}
        placeholder="example MCMXC"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You need to set value for corresponding input anyways. But value for the counterpart needs to be set with converted value.

Here is codesandbox also: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-667fr?file=/src/index.js:100-777

Comment: Thanks, Mario for helping.

Comment: Np. Glad I helped. Cheers